# How to get unicode of characters which converted by tex engine?

Tags: math-mode, unicode, unicode-math

QA:

- Is there a way to log the Unicode characters rendered by each line of source code in the order of the line numbers?
- Regardless of whether it is output as a log, is there any way to get the unicode set corresponding to each formula?

Desired example:

- source code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$x^{4}$ \\
$x\sp{4}$ \\
$x_{4}$
\end{document}
```

- format of log

```
x^{4}\\
Unicode of  x: U+0078\\ % x
Unicode of  4: U+2074\\ % 4 is superscript

x\sp{4}\\
Unicode of  x: U+0078\\ % x
Unicode of  4: U+2074\\ % 4 is superscript

x_{4}\\
Unicode of  x: U+0078\\ % x
Unicode of  4: U+2084\\ % 4 is subscript
```

Comment: I really don't follow too closely what it is you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like you might find Unicode Normalization helpful. There is a package for that for LuaLaTeX: https://ctan.org/pkg/uninormalize

Comment: The 4 isn't U+2074 nor U+2084 in the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandoc to convert the LaTeX code to plain text, then inspect the output with for example `printf` in the terminal. Note that not everything that LaTeX produces is easily convertible to single characters so this will not always work properly.

Also the Pandoc plain text filter cannot handle all arbitrary LaTeX code, even if it is valid, for example `\sp` is not implemented so you need to provide the definition separately.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\sp#1{\ensuremath{^#1}}
\begin{document}
$x^{4}$ \\
$x\sp{4}$ \\
$x_{4}$
\end{document}
```

Pandoc call:

```
pandoc -f latex -t plain yourfile.tex
```

Output:

```
x⁴
x⁴
x₄
```

Showing code points (from https://superuser.com/a/1704946, see also that question for various alternatives using for example Python or Perl if you can't use a Linux terminal):

```bash
pandoc -f latex -t plain yourfile.tex |while read  -n 1 x; do printf '%2s -> %X\n' "$x" "'$x"; done
```

Output:

```
 x -> 78
⁴ -> 2074
   -> 0
 x -> 78
⁴ -> 2074
   -> 0
 x -> 78
₄ -> 2084
   -> 0
```